# Object property lose null after descruction

Tags: typescript

Why is that `y` became string type only after object descruction?

```
const obj: { x: string; y: string | null } = {} as any

const { x, y } = obj // y is string now
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `strictNullChecks` as `true` in your `tsconfig.json`, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks.

Comment: oh, i forgot to add it in second tsconfig :/